# How to use a local DTD file to parse an XML file using lxml?

Tags: python, xml, lxml, dtd

I am trying to parse the DBLP data set using lxml in python. However it is giving this error:

> lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Entity 'uuml' not defined, line 54, column 43

DBLP does provide a `DTD` file for defining entities [here](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/xml/). How can I use that file to parse the DBLP XML document?

Here is my current code:

```
filename = sys.argv[1]
dtd_name = sys.argv[2]
db_name = sys.argv[3]

conn = sqlite3.connect(db_name)

dblp_record_types_for_publications = ('article', 'inproceedings', 'proceedings', 'book', 'incollection',
    'phdthesis', 'masterthesis', 'www')

# read dtd
dtd = ET.DTD(dtd_name) #pylint: disable=E1101

# get an iterable
context = ET.iterparse(filename, events=('start', 'end'), load_dtd=True, #pylint: disable=E1101
    resolve_entities=True) 

# turn it into an iterator
context = iter(context)

# get the root element
event, root = next(context)

n_records_parsed = 0
for event, elem in context:
    if event == 'end' and elem.tag in dblp_record_types_for_publications:
        pub_year = None
        for year in elem.findall('year'):
            pub_year = year.text
        if pub_year is None:
            continue

        pub_title = None
        for title in elem.findall('title'):
            pub_title = title.text
        if pub_title is None:
            continue

        pub_authors = []
        for author in elem.findall('author'):
            if author.text is not None:
                pub_authors.append(author.text)

        # print(pub_year)
        # print(pub_title)
        # print(pub_authors)
        # insert the publication, authors in sql tables
        pub_title_sql_str = pub_title.replace("'", "''")
        pub_author_sql_strs = []
        for author in pub_authors:
            pub_author_sql_strs.append(author.replace("'", "''"))

        conn.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO publications VALUES ('{title}','{year}')".format(
            title=pub_title_sql_str,
            year=pub_year))
        for author in pub_author_sql_strs:
            conn.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO authors VALUES ('{name}')".format(name=author))
            conn.execute("INSERT INTO authored VALUES ('{author}','{publication}')".format(author=author,
                publication=pub_title_sql_str))

        elem.clear()
        root.clear()

        n_records_parsed += 1
        print("No. of records parsed: {}".format(n_records_parsed))

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: If the XML document has a doctype declaration (`<!DOCTYPE dblp SYSTEM "dblp.dtd">`) and if dblp.dtd is in the same directory as the XML file, and if `load_dtd=True` is used, then I don't get any syntax error. I don't think using `dtd = ET.DTD(dtd_name)` has any effect in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After keeping the DTD file in the same directory as the XML file and making sure that DTD filename and the name of the DTD file in the doctype declaration (`<!DOCTYPE dblp SYSTEM "dblp.dtd">`) of the XML document matches, as suggested by mzjn in the comments, it is no longer giving syntax errors.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a custom URI Resolver https://lxml.de/resolvers.html:

```
class DTDResolver(etree.Resolver):
    def resolve(self, system_url, public_id, context):
        return self.resolve_filename(os.path.join("/path/to/dtd/file", system_url), context)

context.resolvers.add(DTDResolver())
```